# adding a custom constructor without losing the default map constructor

Tags: groovy, constructor

By default every Groovy class has a Map constructor, e.g.

```
class Foo {
  def a
  def b
}

// this works
new Foo(a: '1', b: '2')
```

However, it seems that as soon as you add a constructor of your own, this default constructor is not available

```
class Foo {

  Foo(Integer x) {
    println 'my constructor was called'  
  }

  def a
  def b
}

// this works
new Foo(1)

// now this doesn't work, I get the error: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: 
// failed to invoke constructor
new Foo(a: '1', b: '2')
```

**Is it possible to add your own constructor without losing the default map constructor?** I tried annotating the class with `@TupleConstructor` but it made no difference. I realise I could add the map constructor myself, e.g.

```
public Foo(Map map) {    
  map?.each { k, v -> this[k] = v }  
}
```

Though the constructor above is not identical to the default map constructor because a key in the map that does not have a corresponding property in the class will cause an exception.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are on Groovy 2.5 or later, you can apply the `@MapConstructor` [annotation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/MapConstructor.html).

```
@groovy.transform.MapConstructor
class Foo {
    def a, b
    Foo(Integer x) {
        println 'my constructor was called'
    }
}

// this works
new Foo(1)

// the map constructor is present, too
def mappedFoo = new Foo(a: '1', b: '1')
assert mappedFoo.a == '1'
assert mappedFoo.b == '1'
```

If you're using an older version of Groovy, the `@InheritConstructors` [annotation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/InheritConstructors.html) can be used as a substitute for `@MapConstructor`, but as Arie pointed out, avoid this approach if you're class extends some base class; if the base class lacks a no-arg constructor this will not work.

Comment: This is likely the cleaner option.

Comment: This happened to work because `Foo` inherits the default no-arg constructor from the base `Object` class. It will break if the base class doesn't have no-arg constructor, and it will pollute the constructor space if the base class has multiple constructors overloaded. @Will's answer is the right way to go.

Answer (score 13):

Upon compilation, Groovy's map constructor gets translated to an [object creation using an empty constructor plus a bunch of setters](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Default-constructors-td372478.html) (in a javabean style). Having an empty constructor solves the issue:

```
class Foo {

  Foo(Integer x) {
    println 'my constructor was called'  
  }

  Foo() {}

  def a
  def b
}

new Foo(1)

foo = new Foo(a: '1', b: '2')

assert foo.a == "1"
```

Answer (score 7):

Add a no-arg ctor and call `super`, e.g.,

```
class Foo {
  Foo(Integer x) {
    println 'my constructor was called'  
  }

  Foo() { super() } // Or just Foo() {}

  def a
  def b
}

f = new Foo(a: '1', b: '2')
println f.a
=> 1
```